Dovecot quotas with users in MySQL
I have the storage set as mdbox. Trying to get quotas to work with the user information stored in the database, right now with a simple table like this:
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+
| id | domain_id | password                    | email            | quota_bytes |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+
|  1 |         1 | $y$jpasswordpassword.....LC | pawal@example.de | 600M        |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+

This works using the static userdb driver like this:
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
  #driver = sql
  #args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}

Authentication is done with the password_query like this, always works:
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u';

I'm trying to add the user_query like this:
user_query = SELECT email AS user, '/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n' AS home, 'maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as mail, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid, CONC\
AT('*:bytes=', quota_bytes) AS userdb_quota_rule FROM virtual_users WHERE email = '%u';

So far so good. But moving the quota parts is hard. Works with mdbox as long as I have this:
plugin {
  quota = count:User quota
  quota_vsizes = yes
  quota_rule = *:storage=7G
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_max_mail_size = 100M
}

But I never get it to work with anything that comes from MySQL. I am pretty sure it is a dict issue, and I have been playing around with it a lot. Thus, I get error messages like this:
2024-10-23T17:25:40.846512+02:00 mail dovecot: dict(146093): Error: conn unix:dict (pid=146092,uid=5000): Unconfigured dictionary name 'quotadict'
2024-10-23T17:25:40.846799+02:00 mail dovecot: imap(pawal@example.de)<146092><YIuifyYlf9BOQncf>: Error: Failed to get quota resource STORAGE: quota-dict: dict_lookup(priv/quota/storage) failed: Connection closed (reply took 0.030 secs (0.031 in dict wait, 0.000 in other ioloops, 0.000 in locks))

So two questions. The first is, with a database like this, and the need for a quota, with do I put in the plugin for quotas, and what is the dict dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext suppose to look like using these queries?
The second problem I am having. With the current quotas I receive no error message. But when I move the user information with the user_query listed above (even without any quota configuration added to the database nor the query), I receive errors like these:
2024-10-23T15:37:06.934409+02:00 mail dovecot: imap(pawal@example.de)<144888><gXQb7CQllZROQncf>: Error: Failed to get quota resource STORAGE:
 quota-count: Couldn't get size of mailbox dovecot.sieve: stat(/var/mail/vmail/example.de/pawal/.dovecot.sieve/tmp) failed: Not a directory

Any advise on those two questions?

This question is bit confused, the quotadict is related to dict-quota, but you appear to be using quota count, which does not use any dicts.
The second error comes from common misconfiguration of having mail_location = ~/ in which dovecot treats any directory which looks like a maildir directory as folder, and .dovecot-sieve confuses it.
You can fix this by setting sieve_dir = ~/sieve/ and moving sieve related files there or by properly configuring mail_location = ~/mail/ to keep all maildir files in mail directory under user's mail home.

Just put to the dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
# This file is commonly accessed via dict {} section in dovecot.conf

connect = host=127.0.0.1 port=3306 dbname=mail-db user=mail-user password=mail-pass

# CREATE TABLE quota (
#   username varchar(100) not null,
#   bytes bigint not null default 0,
#   messages integer not null default 0,
#   primary key (username)
# );

map {
  pattern = priv/quota/storage
  table = quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = bytes
}
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/messages
  table = quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = messages
}

In table quota you will have only state of data.
In dovecot-sql.conf.ext you will need user_query like this
user_query = \
        SELECT maildir AS home, CONCAT ('maildir:', maildir) AS mail, CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota_bytes, 'M') AS quota_rule FROM virtual_users WHERE email = '%u'

I guess you need to add maildir column to your virtual_users
and to auth-dict.conf.ext you need to add
userdb_objects = userdb

userdb_fields {
  # dict:<key> refers to key names
  quota_rule = *:storage=%{dict:quota}

  # dict:<key>.<objkey> refers to the objkey inside (JSON) object
  mail = maildir:%{dict:userdb.home}/Maildir
}


But I don't use maildir, I use mdbox. Perhaps that the exact thing that makes this troublesome?

imho, you need to add '/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n' AS home to user_query and remove from auth-dict.conf.ext -> userdb_fields -> mail = maildir:%{dict:userdb.home}/Maildir. but in case of mdbox im not expert.
